# ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert doesnt work in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert doesnt work with remote images in Excel 2007... anyone got an alternative method?

```
Public Sub InsertImages()
    Dim iIndex          As Integer
    Dim sImageName      As String
    Dim sImageCell      As String

    For iIndex = 3 To 30
        sImageName = "http://images.server.com" & ActiveSheet.Range("DV" + Trim(Str(iIndex))).Value
        sImageCell = "DW" + Trim(Str(iIndex))


            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(sImageName).Select
            With Selection.ShapeRange
                .Top = Range(sImageCell).Top + 20
                .Left = Range(sImageCell).Left + 20
                .Height = Range(sImageCell).Height - 40
                .Width = Range(sImageCell).Width - 40
            End With

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I just tried your code now with a dummy image from a web server and it appeared to work fine on XL07 SP2. Do you connect through a proxy to the Internet?

Comment: I ran into that problem too. I solved it by saving the image to the hard drive and then inserting the image from that path back to Excel. I don't have the code anymore but I remember that doing it like that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code above, are you passing in correct url?
Does that url fetch an image (such as jpeg) when posted using a browser.

put `Debug.Print sImageName` before `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(sImageName).Select`.
It seems the URL you are generating is incorrect.